# Distribute amount to different instances of balance column

Tags: sql

I have the following Customer table with columns id, name and balance.

I have amount to distribute to each of the rows till the amount becomes 0

it's like this

```
while(Amount>0)
begin
   amount=(Amount)-(select the balance of the row)
     (select the balance column of the row)=0
end
```

I do not want to use the loop or cursor either.

I used the `case` in the update query, but that is not working either.

```
declare @temp decimal(18,4)=1000

update Customer
 set @temp=case
        when @temp>Balance then 
        @temp-Balance
        else @temp
   end,
   Balance=case 
       when Balance<=@temp  then 0
       else Balance
   end
from person 
where Balance<=@temp 

   select @temp
```

Comment: sample data expected result

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code isn't ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: i am using  T-sql

Comment: the code is not the actual code but pseudo code

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results. E.g. three customers A, B, and C with balances 300, 500, 1200. Amount = 1000. What is the expected outcome? And what rule do you apply to get that result?

Comment: A=0,amount=amount -A=1000-300=700

Comment: B=0,amount=200, c=1000,Amount=0

Comment: What makes you start with A? Because it's the first in the alphabet? Or because it has the lowest balance? Or what other rule applies here?

Comment: i need to check row by row ,get the respective  balance column , make it 0 if the Balance column <=Amount , then decrement the amount by the respective balance till the amount becomes 0 please help  Thorsten Kettner

Comment: No, you haven't understood what I am asking. I gave you an example of three suppliers A, B, and C. You immediately "looped" through them in this order. What if I had told you there are three suppliers C, B and A with the balances 1200, 500, and 300. Same data, but you would have shown me a very different result. So: by what order do you want to go through the suppliers?

Comment: lowest Balance first, i.e order by balance asc,the one who has the lowest balance will be cleared first, please help

Comment: it odd the say but its frustating me

Answer (score 0):

Build a running total (with `sum(balance) over(order by balance)`):

```
supplier   balance   total
A          300       300
B          500       800
C          1200      2000
D          1400      3400
```

All rows where `total - balance < @amount` must be updated (this is suppliers A, B, and C in the example above). The ones where `total <= @amount` get reduced to null; the one where `total > @amount` (supplier C in the example above) ends up with the difference of `total - @amount`.

```
update s
set balance = case when total <= @amount then 0 else total - @amount end
(
  select 
    balance, 
    sum(balance) over (order by balance) as total
  from suppliers
) s
where total - balance <= @amount;
```